# Any suggestions for my workflow of developing CMake C++ project based on WSL targeting for remote Linux?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ubuntu, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My current workflow is

1. use Visual Studio 2019 to develop and test CMake C++ project based on WSL.

   - follow https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-with-visual-studio-2019-and-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/
2. copy executable to remote Linux machine(the same Ubuntu distribution as WSL).
3. use GDB to debug this executable. If all is well, code is completed, otherwise go to step 1.

There are two datasets my procedure needs to run along, a small and a big. The big can be only stored at my remote, so I need to test the small locally, and then the big remotely to make sure everything is fine. Typically the small is fine and there are always problems with the big.

Comment: Are there specific compiler flags that are specific to the Linux build vice the VS2019 build? If not, you should be fine with using the Unix Makefiles generator.

Comment: Would also suggest that you keep a smaller dataset on the WSL file system so that you can test locally, if at all possible.

Comment: @scootermefecit yep I do test the small one on WSL locally.

Comment: @scootermefecit VS for Windows can be used to develop a cmake project targeting for WSL/remote Linux. And I think it can generate makefile for Unix automatically, if necessary.